# how to create ripple effect for pre-lollipop

Tags: android, rippledrawable

How to apply ripple effect like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/traex/RippleEffect/master/demo.gif)

i have put the dependencies in app/build.gradle

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
}
```

build.gradle

```
allprojects{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        maven(url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

XML file:

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/rect1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/enterButton"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Save your user name" />
 </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

Java class file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.save_user);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME_STRING, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userNameString=sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME_STRING, "");

    editText.setText(userNameString);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string=editText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(SaveUser.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("user", string);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(USER_NAME_STRING, string);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

it works but my problem is another activity opens before the ripple effect completes and when I press back button the remaining ripple completes. how can I solve it??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try this library [balysv/material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple).

In your gradle, add this line :

```
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

And this is how to do it :

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
android:id="@+id/ripple"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button inside a ripple"/>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Comment: You can perfectly use it for SDK 8, in the description of the library, search for Support for Android api versions < 14 ;)

Comment: LinearLayout should be the parent of MaterialRippleLayout.

Comment: its not good idea because it can support one child in `xml` side .think  if you want do this for 100 button  what happen to you ! and apparently
it cant support java code for do ripple . i tested it for a `button`  but i cant get nice result .

Answer (score 33):

For lollipop(API>21) make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable-v21  and put below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:color="?android:colorAccent"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        <item android:drawable="@color/cancel_btn_clr" /> <!-- default -->
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
```

For pre lollipop (API<21)make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable folder and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/cancel_btn_clr"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Create button as below

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="@style/cancel_btn_style"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    />
```

Add this in your  style.xml

```
          <style name="cancel_btn_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">36dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">90dp</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_ripple_effect</item>
```

Comment: for pre-lollipop devices, what is the parent tag in btn_ripple_effect.xml ?

Comment: @RohitSingh it should be a selector

Comment: No external dependency is needed for this solution, so its a better answer

Comment: it doesn't even give a ripple effect, only the background changes

Answer (score 5):

For lollipop(API>21) make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable-v21 and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f8c7c9c8"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp10" />
            <solid android:color="#f8ced6d2" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

For pre lollipop (API<21)make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable folder and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#f8ced6d2"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

use it on imageview like this

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageViewOffer"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:background="@drawable/btn_ripple_effect"
  android:src="@mipmap/ic_offers"/>
```

Comment: That's not a ripple effect

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but you can perform your action in onRippleCompleteListener provided by the library.
Something like :

```
rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

@Override
public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
//Your code here...
}
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the appcompat libary

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
```

extend "Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"

```
<style name="BrowseContentButton" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_0</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
</style>
```

apply the style

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/browseMultimedia"
        style="@style/BrowseContentButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/browseGuidelines"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/divider"
        android:text="@string/browse_multimedia"
        />
```

Comment: all of these works but my problem is another activity opens before the ripple effect completes and when I press back button the remaining ripple completes. how can I solve it??

Comment: I hav uploaded the java file abov, there is xml file and dependencies too but when the button is clicked, the other page (SaveUser page) opens before the ripple effect completes, how to fix it??

Comment: which ripple? With this code you will not get it on pre-lollipop!