# How to achieve ripple effect in Pre-Lollipop devices?

Tags: android, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

Is there a way to achieve ripple effect in android button in **pre Lollipop** devices **without using 3rd party libraries?**

**I also need to customize the button color and ripple color.** So is this possible through Google support library?

Please note that I don't want to use 3rd party libraries in https://github.com or other similar sites. I just need to know whether this is possible through default android support libraries. Thanks.

Comment: http://mobilenext.net/4-material-design-tweaks-pre-lollipop-android-devices/ Please google first before posting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38394442/7320259 try this

Comment: @Sourav Ganguly I asked is this possible through Google support library. Not through a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT achieve ripple effect to versions prior to 21.However you can refer to other libraries to achieve your requirements.Here are some implementations:
https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable

Comment: @Akshay actually you can do thta without a library . using a subclass of button